# WinForms Async Load Task Does Not Complete

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I am using .NET Framework v4.7.2. I have a simplified version of the original code below.

In my original problem, the `Form_Load()` handler was ending prematurely so I decided to wrap everything from the `Form_Load()` handler inside a `Task` and then in the `Form_Show()` handler (which fires *after* `Form_Load()`) pull out the data I asynchronously loaded in the `Task`. The data I am concerned about is the `stringArray`, which is coming out `null`.

Obviously, I would have preferred to figure out *why* `Form_Load()` was ending prematurely but I had no luck in that.

I know am struggling here and probably missing some fundamental concept. I feel that if I can understand why `stringArray` is `null`, I will understand why my original `Form_Load()` ended prematurely. The `formLoadTask`'s `Status` property is `RanToCompletion` so how could `stringArray` be `null`?

Please remember this is a simplified version of the real code.

Thanks

```
interface IRetriever
{
    Task<String[]> GetStringArray();
}

class Retriever : IRetriever
{
    public async Task<string[]> GetStringArray()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(new string[] { "More", "Larry", "Curly", });
    }
}

static class Director
{
    internal static async Task<IRetriever> CreateRetriever()
    {
        return await Task<IRetriever>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // Simulate some I/O bound waiting...
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return new Retriever();
        });
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static String[] stringArray;
    private static IRetriever retriever;
    internal Task formLoadTask;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        formLoadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            retriever = await Director.CreateRetriever();
            stringArray = await retriever.GetStringArray();

        });
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I know I am tying up the UI thread here. This is just an example.
        formLoadTask.Wait();

        // At this point the formLoadTask is finished, so shouldn't the stringArray be populated?

        // The next line throws a NullReferenceException because stringArray is null.
        // Why??
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(stringArray.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `.Wait()` you should be using `await`. You can make your event handlers async just by changing their signature.

Comment: "This code deadlocks and never reaches the line I get an error on, but ignore that it is just example of something I want to demonstrate" - it's kind of hard to figure out what you doing if you can provide [MCVE] that at least looks like may have a problem you describe...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov. I never said the code deadlocks. I explained what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StartNew` doesn't recognize your async delegate. It is treating it as a `Func<Task>` that nobody ends up awaiting. The task that you're storing in `formLoadTask` is just the task that started the task, not the task itself.

You can either unwrap the task or use the more modern `Task.Run`, which handles async delegates properly.

```
formLoadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    retriever = await Director.CreateRetriever();
    stringArray = await retriever.GetStringArray();
}).Unwrap();
```

or (preferred):

```
formLoadTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    retriever = await Director.CreateRetriever();
    stringArray = await retriever.GetStringArray();
});
```